# Fetching only several result sets

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

The question is quite simple. I have following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1

SELECT *
FROM T2

SELECT *
FROM T3

SELECT *
FROM T4
```

In one case I need all four data sets, in other I need only `T1` and `T2`.
Should I write another stored procedure which returns only `T1` and `T2`, or can I just skip last two data sets (without executing batch on SQL engine).

I mean if I fetch only `T1` and `T2` with following code

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
ReadSet1();
reader.NextResult();
ReadSet2();
reader.Close()
```

does SQL server actually executes batches for `T3` and `T4`?

Comment: Do you have your SQL statements in a procedure? If yes, you could add a parameter (eg. `@tablesToLoad` or something like this) to it and get the desired results by using an `IF` statement in the procedure.

Comment: `In one case I need all four data sets, in other I need only T1 and T2`,best bet would be to write seperate stored procs for each case

Comment: @diiN_ of course, I have a control over programm flow and can do everything. My question is primarily about if SQL Server executes entire procedure before sending results, or it executes each result set separately?

Comment: I'd assume, that **one procedure is one job...** How should SQL Server get to know, that in this special case you will not need T3? Neither your application can predict this in any case, nor can this be done by SQL-Server...

Comment: @Shnugo engine could not perform execution for next `Result Set` until previous one is not fetched by client, for example.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy, well, I cannot imagine, that this would make any sense... Your application could decide much later (maybe waiting for user-input). When should the transaction of this SP should be commited? No, I'm pretty sure, that the job is worked out and the results are fetched for all selects. As pointed in my answer you might use the Profiler to monitor the point of execution. Just insert some kind of wait loop before you fetch the next result...

Comment: with the reader if the client takes time to consume them then SQL Server will be blocked with a wait type of asynch network io it doesn't just race ahead and prepare the whole resultset in server memory. I imagine (without testing) that it will start the rest and whether or not it finishes depends on the result set size vs network packet size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reader will only read so far ahead

It may start the NextResult(); but it won't execute it all unless it fits in the buffer

Try this
After you read T1 change a value in T4
You will see the new value (unless the row count is low)
You would not see the new value if SQL ran all 4 at the start

You can also return a getdate for a measure of when the row is fetched

Comment: Are you sure? This should depend on isolation level, transaction scope and many more influences ...

Comment: @Shnugo Test for yourself.  This is the results I got.

Comment: @Paparazzi I think transaction scrope may change this behaviour and require more testing, but it works for non-transaction selects at least.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server does not know what you are doing with the result sets within your application, it will prepare all resultsets whether you need them or not. At least I think so.

You might open the Profiler to monitor at which moment the `SELECT` takes place, all at once or one after the other... But I'm quite sure, that the procedure runs for all...

You might:

- create one procedure for each `SELECT` (better an inline table valued function actually). This is - for sure! - the better and cleaner approach, but might have great impact on the calling application's code. Or
- pass in parameters like `@LoadT1 BIT, @LoadT2 BIT...` and load after `IF`. In C#-code there is - probably - an existing function or method to execute the call. Just give this function 4 boolean parameters with default values (optional paramteres). Any existing code would not have to be changed. But in cases where this makes sense you might just set the appropriate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The ExecuteReader will execute the proc in its entirety.  If you watch profiler and put delays in your code in between steps you will see that.  The other steps you have aren't against the proc, they against the executed result of the proc in the form of your reader.

What you should do is a matter of opinion and tradeoff.  On the one hand, if you use the same proc you have the advantage of code reuse and half as many places to change code if something needs to be modified for dataset 1 or 2.  On the other hand, if you separate them (either into two procs or four) you have an advantage of efficiency.  So it really comes down to how expensive the queries are ... at least that is what would be the decider to me.  Generally I would say the best way to do it would be to have 4 separate procs, but if they are really low impact queries I don't know that I would spend the time.

The other option, which Shnugo brought up, would be to have one or more parameters ... say maybe a @returnAll4 BIT.  The app would pass that and if it's 0/false you can avoid the execution of the 3rd and 4th datasets by putting a WHERE @returnAll4 = 1 filter on them.  You would still see those in the execution plan, but they won't actually do anything other than that filter evaluation.  I have used that approach, but I tend to stay away from it because I am concerned it may be a bit unclear to another developer in the future.

Comment: I think there is a solution much simpler: Create the SP with four parameters, one for each table. In C#-code there is - probably - an existing function or method to execute the call. Just give this function 4 boolean parameters with default values (optional paramteres). Any existing code would not have to be changed. But in cases where this makes sense you might just set the appropriate paramter. This is what I  had in mind writing my answer...